# ActionBarTabs in Fragment class instead of Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, actionbarsherlock

I am working on a project in which I am using ActionBarSherlock library.Now i want to create tabs with viewpager.

So i used [this](http://www.androidgreeve.com/2014/02/android-actionbar-tabs-with-swipeable.html) tutorial for reference.The class in which I want to create tabview is a `Fragment`, not an `Activity`.

Somebody please help me with converting these methods which I used in `Activity` class into methods of `Fragment`.

First:

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
```

> Error:The method getSupportActionBar() is undefined for the type Fragment

Second:

```
viewPager.setAdapter(new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));
```

> Error:The method getSupportFragmentManager() is undefined for the type Fragment

Comment: seems you are not using support library, so just remove all `support` from api, and I suppose your `minSDKVersion` is >=11

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActivity().getSupportActionBar();
```

And

```
viewPager.setAdapter(new ViewPagerAdapter(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()));
```